# How to solve this Compile error caused by a .PasteSpecial?

Tags: vba, compilation, copy, paste

I'm trying to get my head around the following but can't get the code to work.

```
    Sub Copy_Paste_Below_Last_Cell()
'Find the last used row in both sheets and copy and paste data below existing data.

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

  'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
  Set wsCopy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
  Set wsDest = Workbooks("Data.xlsx").Worksheets("DB")

  '1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column A
  lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

  '2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column A
  'Offset property moves down 1 row
  lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

  '3. Copy & Paste Data
  wsCopy.Range("A2:H" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
  wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues



End Sub
```

The problem appears on the last line. Without the addition of PasteSpecial xlPasteValues the script runs perfectly. However as it is pulling from a large sheet with lines that have a formule in, the destination sheet gets filled with empty lines with formulas. When I rerun the script with new data it then looks for the latest empty row, but due to the formulas this is hunders of lines down from the actual data.

Visualisation:

```
Data Row 1
Data Row2
Formula row
Formula row
Empty row
```

Run 2

```
Data Row 1
Data Row2
Formula row
Formula row
Data Row 3
Formula Row
```

Comment: `PasteSpecial` needs to be on a separate line - remove the underscore on the previous line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it is because the Copy and PasteSpecial methods are on the same line. Try the below, it should work.

```
 Sub Copy_Paste_Below_Last_Cell()
'Find the last used row in both sheets and copy and paste data below existing data.

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

  'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
  Set wsCopy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
  Set wsDest = Workbooks("Data.xlsx").Worksheets("DB")

  '1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column A
  lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

  '2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column A
  'Offset property moves down 1 row
  lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

  '3. Copy & Paste Data
  wsCopy.Range("A2:H" & lCopyLastRow).Copy
  wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Added `Application.CutCopyMode = False` to clear the clipboard once the copy paste is executed.

Comment: I was already wondering why the _ sign was there. Many thanks for the help! However it has not solved the bigger issue of copying empty cells.

Comment: _ means the line is continuing further. This is added to make the big code readable but as per VBA it is just one line. You will have to write further lines to ignore blanks and cannot be done with this set of codes.